# How to define props on framer-motion styled-component? (PSA)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, typescript-generics, framer-motion

## PSA:

*(not a question but I didn't see any answers to this on stack so here's the answer.)*

Define props on a styled-components that wraps a motion, it's a little confusing how to define them when wrapping motion with `styled()`.

how to define props according to styled components [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props)

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Header from './Header';

interface TitleProps {
  readonly isActive: boolean;
}

const Title = styled.h1<TitleProps>`
  color: ${(props) => (props.isActive ? props.theme.colors.main : props.theme.colors.secondary)};
`;
```

How to define the props in your code **without** motion:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

interface Props {
  height?: number;
}

const Container = styled.div<Props>`
  height: ${({ height }) => height};
`;

export default Container;
```

How to define the props in your code **with** motion:

```js
import { HTMLMotionProps, motion } from "framer-motion";
import styled from "styled-components";

/**
 * notice the props extend HTMLMotionProps<"div"> this is so all the default
 * props are passed such as `onClick`
 */
interface Props extends HTMLMotionProps<"div"> {
  height?: number;
}

//notice motion is called as a function instead of `motion.div`
const Container = styled(motion<Props>("div"))`
  height: ${({ height }) => height};
`;

export default Container;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining your "motion div" wrong. It should be defined this way instead:

```
interface Props {
  height?: number;
}

// motion is an object that gives you access to the html tags (like the div)
const Container = styled(motion.div)<Props>`
  height: ${({ height }) => height};
`;
```

As you can see above, you just need to pass in `motion.div` as any other component, into the `styled` function.